Ubuntu Server website files turned into ( filename.extentiosn.locked)
MY website files and some system files turned to (ex.  wp-config.php.locked)
any one know what is this and how to fix ?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read How do I ask a good question? And provide us more details. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
